# Hibernate: Creating an index for an ElementCollection table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-postgresql

```
@Entity
public class FruitStore {

@Id
private Long storeId;

@ElementCollection
private Set<Fruit> fruits;

}
```

Of course, the `Fruit` class is marked `@Embeddable`.

In the database (postgresql to be exact, although it shouldn't matter), there is a table created called `fruitstore_fruits`. It grows huge, and queries on it become very very slow. I have manually modified the database, such that the `fruitstore_fruits` table indexes on the `FruitStore` `id` column. Happily, this dramatically improves performance. I want this to be done automatically.

The question is, how can I annotate my code to get Hibernate to automatically index the fruitstore_fruits on the `FruitStore` `id` column?

**EDIT:** [This Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4263) has removed lots of hope. I think what I want is simply not supported right now. Which is kinda sad, because the feature isn't that exotic (indexing a element collection with a foreign column). However, I'd *love* to be proven wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried using a Hibernate Column Index?  This grokbase post seems to indicate that creating a separate column index may be a viable solution: http://grokbase.com/p/postgresql/pgsql-performance/088mdgp5ar/postgresql-hibernate-performance

Comment: As that discussion points out, there is no such thing as a Hibernate Column Index. Instead, one uses Hibernate to create an index over a particular column in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look for example of how it could be done:

@CollectionTable(indexes = {@Index(columnList = "solution_version_training_session_id")})